# R - Assigning Plot to Variably Named List

Tags: r, assign

I am trying to assign a plot to a list that is named via variable (**snm**). My code snippet is all the variations that I tried to do to make it work. What other option am I missing? Thanks.

My goal is to loop over my graph assignments, using an IF statement to change the **snm** and a few other variables that I will use in the graphs.

```
for (x in seq(0,1)) {
  if (x==0) {
    snm="grad"
  } 
  else if (x==1) {
    snm="start"
  }

    assign(snm,list(),envir=.GlobalEnv) #works
    assign(snm[[1]],ggplot(data=TDSF, aes(x=Graduation))+geom_histogram()+labs(title="A"),envir=.GlobalEnv) #works
    assign(snm[[2]],ggplot(data=TDSF, aes(x=Graduation,weights=Donation))+geom_bar()+labs(title="B"),envir=.GlobalEnv) #fails "subscript out of bonds"
    assign(snm[[3]],ggplot(data=TDSF, aes(x=State,weights=Donation))+geom_bar()+labs(title="B")+scale_y_sqrt(),envir=.GlobalEnv) #fails "subscript out of bonds"
    grid.arrange(grad[[1]],grad[[2]],grad[[3]])
}
```

Partial solution based on @MrFlick and @hrbrmstr, but 1) I have to use do.call in the loop or I get the same graphs and 2) seeing mapply I feel that I should be able to use it, but cannot get it to work.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(1492)
TDSF <- data.frame(Graduation=sample(1950:2010, 30),
                   Donation=sample(300:10000, 30),
                   Start.Year=sample(1950:2010,30),
                   State=sample(state.abb,30,replace=TRUE))

plots <- list()
for (x in seq(0,1)) {
  if (x==0) {
    nm=quote(Graduation)
    snm="grad"
  } 
  else if (x==1) {
    nm=quote(Start.Year)
    snm="start"
  }
  plots[[snm]]<-list()
  plots[[snm]][[1]] <- ggplot(data=TDSF, aes(x=eval(nm)))+geom_histogram()+labs(title=paste("Number of People per",snm,"Year"))
  plots[[snm]][[2]] <- ggplot(data=TDSF, aes(x=eval(nm),weights=Donation))+geom_bar()+labs(title=paste("Donations by",snm,"Year"))
  plots[[snm]][[3]] <- ggplot(data=TDSF, aes(x=State,weights=Donation))+geom_bar()+labs(title="Donations by State")+scale_y_sqrt()
}

do.call(grid.arrange,plots[["grad"]])
do.call(grid.arrange,plots[["start"]])
```

mapply attempt:

```
plot<-mapply(function(snm,nm) list(
  {ggplot(data=TDSF, aes(x=nm))+geom_histogram()+labs(title=paste("Number of People per",snm,"Year"))},
  {ggplot(data=TDSF, aes(x=nm,weights=Donation))+geom_bar()+labs(title=paste("Donations by",snm,"Year"))},
  {ggplot(data=TDSF, aes(x=State,weights=Donation))+geom_bar()+labs(title="Donations by State")+scale_y_sqrt()}
), c("grad","start"),c("Graduation","Start.Year"),SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

do.call(grid.arrange,plot[["grad"]])
do.call(grid.arrange,plot[["start"]])
```

Comment: "Good" R code doesn't use `assign()`. I suggest you break your habit of that as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick . How do I assign to a variable then? I tried eval(snm)<- but it would not work.

Comment: Don't use `eval()` either. Typically you just need to smartly use named lists. That's what most functions are designed to work best with, not a bunch of individual variables. If you want two collections, one for "grad" and "start", use `x <- list(grad=list(), start=list())`. Then you can do `x[["grad"][[1]] <- ggplot(...)` or whateer.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick that makes a lot of sense now that I see it.

Answer (score 1):

Despite a lengthy code snippet, your question really isn't clear. Are you trying to do something like this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(1492)
TDSF <- data.frame(Graduation=sample(1950:2010, 30),
                   Donation=sample(300:10000, 30))

snm <- mapply(function(x, title) {
  ggplot(TDSF, aes_(x=as.name(x))) + 
    geom_histogram() + 
    labs(title=title) 
}, c("Graduation", "Donation"), c("A", "B"), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

do.call(grid.arrange, snm)
```

Comment: Sorry. New to R and Stack Overflow (posting at least). That is a totally different approach than I was doing, but may work better. However, I am trying to name something to snm, but let snm change. So I end of with grad[[1]], grad[[[2]] and then init[[1]], init[[2]]

Comment: Revised my OP to hopefully make more sense

Comment: Solved it. I was not familiar with **aes_** vs just plain **aes** and missed it in your example

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted to do originally is not possible in that exact manner. However, based on the feedback I was able to create a list of lists of ggplots. This condenses my out down to 1 variable versus the 2 I was targeting. Instead of `start[[1]]` to plot the first graph I use `plot[["start"]][[1]]`. Makes sense when you read it, but was not how I expected. I come from VBA and python so R is new format.

Mapply is also incredibly more powerful/simple approach than I was originally doing, so thanks for that input.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(1492)
TDSF <- data.frame(Graduation=sample(1950:2010, 30),
                   Donation=sample(300:10000, 30),
                   Start.Year=sample(1950:2010,30),
                   State=sample(state.abb,30,replace=TRUE))

    plot<-mapply(function(snm,nm) list(
      {ggplot(data=TDSF, aes_q(x=as.name(nm)))+geom_histogram()+labs(title=paste("Number of People per",snm,"Year"))},
      {ggplot(data=TDSF, aes_q(x=as.name(nm),weights=~Donation))+geom_bar()+labs(title=paste("Donations by",snm,"Year"))},
      {ggplot(data=TDSF, aes(x=State,weights=Donation))+geom_bar()+labs(title="Donations by State")+scale_y_sqrt()}
    ), c("grad","start"),c("Graduation","Start.Year"),SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

    do.call(grid.arrange,plot[["grad"]])
    do.call(grid.arrange,plot[["start"]])
```